# django migrations how to refer to an inner class inside model

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am looking to refer to a inner class 'Code' under the model 'Evaluation'. Basically both of these options DO NOT work (Option:1)

```
code = apps.get_model('my_project', 'Evaluation.Code')
```

OR (Option:2)

```
evaluation = apps.get_model('my_project', 'Evaluation')
code = evaluation.Code
```

Option:1 throws me this error:

```
grzsqrrel@grzsqrreld:~/PycharmProjects/my_project/my_project$ python manage.py migrate
    local_settings.py not found
    Operations to perform:
    Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, django_cron, sessions, my_project_app
    Running migrations:
    Applying my_project_app.0002_load_items...Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/grzsqrrel/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363,...
    File "/home/grzsqrrel/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 193, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
    File "/home/grzsqrrel/PycharmProjects/my_project/my_project/my_project_app/migrations/0002_load_items.py", line 7, in load_data
    code = evaluation.Code
    AttributeError: type object 'Evaluation' has no attribute 'Code'
```

models.py:

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    class Code:
```

0002_load_items.py

```
def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    evaluation = apps.get_model('my_project', 'Evaluation')
    code = evaluation.Code

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('my_project', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data)
    ]
```

What'd be the fix? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a list of static codes which I would refer from the inner class
my_model.objects.create(item_code=code.COURSES_TAUGHT)

Comment: But why would those need to be image another class? Why not make them `Evaluation.COURSES_TAUGHT`? Or even at module level? Python is not Java, there's no reason to create classes unless you're storing state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turned out, the answer is elsewhere. Since I am not creating objects using the inner class, I can use conventional import.

```
from django.db import migrations
from my_project.models import Evaluation

def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    evaluation = apps.get_model('my_project', 'Evaluation')
    code = Evaluation.Code
    my_model.objects.create(item_code=code.COURSES_TAUGHT)
```